# Taking a picture in my app and saving it in the gallery

Tags: java, android, android-camera, android-mediascanner

I'm aware that this question has been asked before but all of the answers I have looked at have failed to give me the answer (most probably because some of them I can't understand but also because there are a lot of different solutions it seems and I can't see the wood for the trees).

I'm hoping that by providing my code that someone will be able to point me in the right direction.

Here is my class used to take the picture:

```
public class CameraPhotoActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private Button btnCapture;
private TextureView textureView;

// to check the state orientation of the output image
private static final SparseIntArray ORIENTATIONS = new SparseIntArray();

static {
    ORIENTATIONS.append(Surface.ROTATION_0, 90);
    ORIENTATIONS.append(Surface.ROTATION_90, 0);
    ORIENTATIONS.append(Surface.ROTATION_180, 270);
    ORIENTATIONS.append(Surface.ROTATION_270, 180);
}

private String cameraId;
private CameraDevice cameraDevice;
private CameraCaptureSession cameraCaptureSessions;
private CaptureRequest.Builder captureRequestBuilder;
private Size imageDimension;
private ImageReader imageReader;

// save to file
private File file;
private static final int REQUEST_CAMERA_PERMISSION = 200;
private boolean mFlashSupported;
private Handler mBackgroundHandler;
private HandlerThread mBackgroundThread;

CameraDevice.StateCallback stateCallback = new CameraDevice.StateCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onOpened(@NonNull CameraDevice camera) {
        cameraDevice = camera;
        createCameraPreview();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDisconnected(@NonNull CameraDevice cameraDevice) {
        cameraDevice.close();
    }

    @Override
    public void onError(@NonNull CameraDevice cameraDevice, int i) {
        cameraDevice.close();
        cameraDevice = null;
    }
};


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_camera_photo);

    textureView = (TextureView) findViewById(R.id.textureView);
    assert textureView != null;
    textureView.setSurfaceTextureListener(textureListener);
    btnCapture = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnCapture);
    btnCapture.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            takePicture();
        }
    });
}

private void takePicture() {

    if (cameraDevice == null)
        return;
    CameraManager manager = (CameraManager) getSystemService(Context.CAMERA_SERVICE);
    try {
        CameraCharacteristics characteristics = manager.getCameraCharacteristics(cameraDevice.getId());
        Size[] jpegSizes = null;
        if (characteristics != null)
            jpegSizes = characteristics.get(CameraCharacteristics.SCALER_STREAM_CONFIGURATION_MAP)
                    .getOutputSizes(ImageFormat.JPEG);

        // capture the image with custom size
        int width = 640;
        int height = 480;
        if (jpegSizes != null && jpegSizes.length > 0) {
            width = jpegSizes[0].getWidth();
            height = jpegSizes[0].getHeight();
        }
        final ImageReader reader = ImageReader.newInstance(width, height, ImageFormat.JPEG, 1);
        List<Surface> outputSurface = new ArrayList<>(2);
        outputSurface.add(reader.getSurface());
        outputSurface.add(new Surface(textureView.getSurfaceTexture()));

        final CaptureRequest.Builder captureBuilder = cameraDevice.createCaptureRequest(CameraDevice.TEMPLATE_STILL_CAPTURE);
        captureBuilder.addTarget(reader.getSurface());
        captureBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_MODE, CameraMetadata.CONTROL_MODE_AUTO);

        // check the orientation on the device
        int rotation = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getRotation();
        captureBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.JPEG_ORIENTATION, ORIENTATIONS.get(rotation));

        file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/" + UUID.randomUUID().toString()
                + ".jpg");
        ImageReader.OnImageAvailableListener readerListener = new ImageReader.OnImageAvailableListener() {
            @Override
            public void onImageAvailable(ImageReader imageReader) {
                Image image = null;
                try {
                    image = reader.acquireLatestImage();
                    ByteBuffer buffer = image.getPlanes()[0].getBuffer();
                    byte[] bytes = new byte[buffer.capacity()];
                    buffer.get(bytes);
                    save(bytes);
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } finally {
                    {
                        if (image != null)
                            image.close();
                    }
                }
            }

            private void save(byte[] bytes) throws IOException {
                OutputStream outputStream = null;
                try {
                    outputStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
                    outputStream.write(bytes);
                } finally {
                    if (outputStream != null)
                        outputStream.close();
                }



            }
        };

        reader.setOnImageAvailableListener(readerListener, mBackgroundHandler);
        final CameraCaptureSession.CaptureCallback captureListener = new CameraCaptureSession.CaptureCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onCaptureCompleted(@NonNull CameraCaptureSession session, @NonNull CaptureRequest request, @NonNull TotalCaptureResult result) {
                super.onCaptureCompleted(session, request, result);
                Toast.makeText(CameraPhotoActivity.this, "Saved " + file, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                createCameraPreview();
            }
        };

        cameraDevice.createCaptureSession(outputSurface, new CameraCaptureSession.StateCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onConfigured(@NonNull CameraCaptureSession cameraCaptureSession) {
                try {
                    cameraCaptureSession.capture(captureBuilder.build(), captureListener, mBackgroundHandler);
                } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onConfigureFailed(@NonNull CameraCaptureSession cameraCaptureSession) {

            }
        }, mBackgroundHandler);


    } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private void createCameraPreview() {
    try {
        SurfaceTexture texture = textureView.getSurfaceTexture();
        assert texture != null;
        texture.setDefaultBufferSize(imageDimension.getWidth(), imageDimension.getHeight());
        Surface surface = new Surface(texture);
        captureRequestBuilder = cameraDevice.createCaptureRequest(CameraDevice.TEMPLATE_PREVIEW);
        captureRequestBuilder.addTarget(surface);
        cameraDevice.createCaptureSession(Arrays.asList(surface), new CameraCaptureSession.StateCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onConfigured(@NonNull CameraCaptureSession cameraCaptureSession) {
                if (cameraDevice == null)
                    return;
                cameraCaptureSessions = cameraCaptureSession;
                updatePreview();
            }

            @Override
            public void onConfigureFailed(@NonNull CameraCaptureSession cameraCaptureSession) {
                Toast.makeText(CameraPhotoActivity.this, "Changed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }, null);
    } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private void updatePreview() {
    if (cameraDevice == null)
        Toast.makeText(this, "Error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    captureRequestBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_MODE, CaptureRequest.CONTROL_MODE_AUTO);
    try {
        cameraCaptureSessions.setRepeatingRequest(captureRequestBuilder.build(), null, mBackgroundHandler);
    } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private void openCamera() {
    CameraManager manager = (CameraManager) getSystemService(Context.CAMERA_SERVICE);
    try {
        cameraId = manager.getCameraIdList()[0];
        CameraCharacteristics characteristics = manager.getCameraCharacteristics(cameraId);
        StreamConfigurationMap map = characteristics.get(CameraCharacteristics.SCALER_STREAM_CONFIGURATION_MAP);
        assert map != null;
        imageDimension = map.getOutputSizes(SurfaceTexture.class)[0];
        // check realtime permission if run higher than API 23
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.CAMERA) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{
                    Manifest.permission.CAMERA,
                    Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
            }, REQUEST_CAMERA_PERMISSION);
            return;
        }
        manager.openCamera(cameraId, stateCallback, null);

    } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

TextureView.SurfaceTextureListener textureListener = new TextureView.SurfaceTextureListener() {
    @Override
    public void onSurfaceTextureAvailable(SurfaceTexture surfaceTexture, int i, int i1) {
        openCamera();
    }

    @Override
    public void onSurfaceTextureSizeChanged(SurfaceTexture surfaceTexture, int i, int i1) {

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onSurfaceTextureDestroyed(SurfaceTexture surfaceTexture) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onSurfaceTextureUpdated(SurfaceTexture surfaceTexture) {

    }
};

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_CAMERA_PERMISSION) {
        if (grantResults[0] != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "You can't use the camera without permission", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            finish();
        }
    }
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    startBackgroundThread();
    if (textureView.isAvailable())
        openCamera();
    else
        textureView.setSurfaceTextureListener(textureListener);
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    stopBackgroundThread();
    super.onPause();
}

private void stopBackgroundThread() {
    mBackgroundThread.quitSafely();
    try {
        mBackgroundThread.join();
        mBackgroundThread = null;
        mBackgroundHandler = null;
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private void startBackgroundThread() {
    mBackgroundThread = new HandlerThread("Camera Background");
    mBackgroundThread.start();
    mBackgroundHandler = new Handler(mBackgroundThread.getLooper());
}
}
```

I have tried adding the following but, if it's correct, I can't seem to put it in the correct place:

```
MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(this, new String[]{file.toString()}, null,
                        new MediaScannerConnection.OnScanCompletedListener() {
                            public void onScanCompleted(String path, Uri uri) {
                                Log.i("External Storage", "Scanned" + path + ":");
                                Log.i("External Storage", "-> uri=" + uri);
                            }
                        });
```

Thanks for any help.  Much appreciated.

Comment: What error you are getting using above code?

Comment: Wrong first argument type  - and it's for 'this'.  I'm putting this code below the 'save' method.  Is that correct?

Comment: can you please tell me in which line you are getting error -"wrong first argument type"

Comment: It's the first line of the code beginning 'MediaScannerConnection'.  Where you see 'this', it is underlined in red and hovering over it gives the message 'wrong first argument type'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This means "context". You need to place the code within the activity class, once the image has been fetched from the camera. Also call connect before calling scanFile. You can try below code.

```
MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(CameraPhotoActivity.this, new String[]{file.toString()}, null,
                        new MediaScannerConnection.OnScanCompletedListener() {
                            public void onScanCompleted(String path, Uri uri) {
                                Log.i("External Storage", "Scanned" + path + ":");
                                Log.i("External Storage", "-> uri=" + uri);
                            }
                        });
```

Comment: Do you know, I was on the verge of trying that when you posted this.  You just confirmed my thinking.  That's why I've up-voted your answer and marked it as correct.  Thanks